# How can I get the program to run again after selecting yes?

Tags: python

I'm trying to let program run until user won't type "No". Here's code I've already done:

```
print("What language would you prefer?\n e for English, s for spanish, f for french")

choice= input("Your choice\n")

english= "Hello iso-3166-2: en-us"
french= "Salut! iso-3166-2:fr"
spanish= "Ola iso-3166-2:es"

if choice == "e":
    print (english)
elif choice == "f":
    print (french)
elif choice == "s":
    print (spanish) 

while True:
    res= input("Do you want to choose another language? Yes/No:")
    if res == "No":
        break
```

Comment: you should put the whole thing inside a loop, like `while True:` instead of just the last part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
english= "Hello iso-3166-2: en-us"
french= "Salut! iso-3166-2:fr"
spanish= "Ola iso-3166-2:es"

print("What language would you prefer?\n e for English, s for spanish, f for french")

choice = input("Your choice\n")

while True:
    if choice == "e":
        print(english)
    elif choice == "f":
        print(french)
    elif choice == "s":
        print(spanish)
    res = input("Do you want to choose another language? Yes/No:")
    if res == 'Yes':
        print("What language would you prefer?\n e for English, s for spanish, f for french")
        choice = input("Your choice\n")
    elif res == 'No':
        print ("Goodbye")
        break
```

output:

```
What language would you prefer?
 e for English, s for spanish, f for french
Your choice
e
Hello iso-3166-2: en-us
Do you want to choose another language? Yes/No:Yes
What language would you prefer?
 e for English, s for spanish, f for french
Your choice
f
Salut! iso-3166-2:fr
Do you want to choose another language? Yes/No:No
Goodbye
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import the sys library first then put the rest of your code in a While True loop. At the end of your code write:

```
Answer = input ("Do you want to continue? (y/n)")
If Answer == 'n' :
    sys.exit
```

Pay attention that the code above is the last thing in the while true loop